# How to clear a repeating field in a dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have an example of data like as follows.

```
ID      | Item
--------|-------
000001  | Blah
000001  | Blah
000001  | Blah 
000002  | Blah 
000002  | Blah 
000003  | Blah
```

I want to have it if the ID is repeating, then the duplicates are blanked. So it appears like this.

```
ID      | Item
--------|-------
000001  | Blah
        | Blah 
        | Blah 
000002  | Blah 
        | Blah 
000003  | Blah
```

At the moment I am sorting the whole data frame by ID, then using `df.iterrows()`, while storing previous value to compare. I am wondering if there is a better/correct way to do this in relation to pandas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this using a [boolean mask](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and passing [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.duplicated.html#pandas.Series.duplicated):

```
In [133]:
df.loc[df['ID'].duplicated(), 'ID'] = ''
df

Out[133]:
       ID  Item
0  000001  Blah
1          Blah
2          Blah
3  000002  Blah
4          Blah
5  000003  Blah
```

Here `duplicated` returns true for the duplicated values:

```
In [135]:
df['ID'].duplicated()

Out[135]:
0    False
1     True
2     True
3    False
4     True
5    False
Name: ID, dtype: bool
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks.